# get statistics by event filters or normal blockchain traversal

Tags: go-ethereum, events, address.transfer, filters

I want to ask what's the better approach among the following two: Filter events using address.eventFilter function or traversing the local blockchain block by block and getting events statistics. I suppose in the former approach we need the contract abi, so what if we can't find the contract's abi? Are all contracts' abis available?

Comment: You don't need the abi.

Comment: More precisely, you don't need to find it. If you know what you want to do, then you can write the abi yourself.

Comment: Even if I am not the creator of the contract? I am talking about filtering events for any random contract address.

Comment: Do you know what event you want to filter?

Comment: yes i want to filter all events which are counted as erc 721 token transfers

Comment: Well, for ERC20, you can use `[{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]`. I guess you can easily adjust this one to ERC721.